# Using GET and inserting a variable in the URL bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, variables, get

I'm stumped!

This will function - notice how the `id` number is placed within the URL in this `GET` statement

`GET https://api.discogs.com/artists/8760?callback=callbackname`

Returns the following string (truncated):

`({"meta": {"status": 200}, "data": {"name": "Madonna", "id": 8760, "resource_url": "https://api.example.com/artists/8760"`.....

The id number is `8760` for this artist

I've tried this and keep returning with errors because of quotations or braces and my variable is not being passed to the $shell:

`id=8760`

`GET https://api.discogs.com/artists/"$id"?callback=callbackname`

`GET https://api.discogs.com/artists/"$id"?callback=callbackname`

`GET https://api.discogs.com/artists/"'$id'"?callback=callbackname`

`GET https://api.discogs.com/artists/'"$id"'?callback=callbackname`

they all return a variety of errors and do not return the correct output if I simply typed in the number instead of using a variable

Comment: Does $id has a value ? and I believe u r using curl. Can't you just give $id without any quotes. And also paste the error u get

Answer (score 0):

Try forming your URL in an `echo` statement and store it in a variable. Then use `get` on the variable.